# e-signature in document with nodejs and ejs

Tags: node.js

Greetings!!

I am facing e-signature issue of my website. 
I have a website which is built in nodejs and ejs. There will be document which will be signed by logged in user. I have followed the URL https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/signing-from-your-app and I have also followed https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant but could not meet my client's requirement.

Comment: Please specify, what exact error or issue you are facing to achieving this

Comment: when I am using first reference I am always getting PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",\r\n  "message": "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified   and when I am using second reference and runs as http://localhost:5000/  it shows   so many links which leads docusign